# laravel error - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel, request

I'm receiving the Non object error  (Trying to get property of non-object) when posting data to my summary view (blade).   running **dd($data);** on the controller returns the payload data correctly (ie flyingFrom, flyingTo)

**Form Payload**

FlyingFrom

FlyingTo

**Controller**

```
 $locations = MyLocations::all()->toJson();
 $data = $request->all();
 return view('summary', compact('data','locations'));
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($data as $locationData)
{{$locationData->flyingFrom}}
{{$locationData->flyingTo}}
@endforeach
```

**Error**

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
resources/views/planner_newsummary.blade.php:28

      <div class="container">

        <div class="col-12">


          <h1 class="ml-2">Book this trip</h1>


            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-sm-6 my-4">


                <div class="card inputcard h-100 progress-step is-complete">

                  <div class="card-header">

                    <i class="fas fa-plane-departure"></i> Flying from

                  </div>

                  <div style="position:relative">



                    <div id="flyingFrom" style="position:relative">{{$locationData->flyingFrom}}</div>

                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- just access your data directly
- `$data = $request->all();` returns array
- in your blade `{{$data[flyingFrom]}}`

Comment: I tried this before.. it still didnt work. I also thought if using "Compact" it creates an array, therefore you need to iterate through it? ErrorException
Trying to get property 'flyingFrom' of non-object (View: @RedaTaha

Comment: I updated the post with the error @RedaTaha.  I'm unable to post a screenshot.. I can tell you that when I use F12 on the network page I can see the Request variables in the FORM DATA on the blade(view)

Comment: ErrorException
Undefined offset: 0 :   I changed the view to {{$data[0]->flyingTo}}  @Redhaha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227613/discussion-between-craig-johnstone-and-reda-taha).

Comment: Show me dd($data);